# Getting started with C# and Databases

Tags: learning, c#, sql

I want to start using Databases in my C# Applications, unfortunately there appears to be lots of different ways of going about this.

Which is the 'best' way from a learning perspective? (IE: What is likely to be used in a business setup)?

If I want to download mySQL/Postgres and connect to that from C#, is that ok?

Comment: C# works best with SQL server,it sucks,but it's the truth,and if you want to get started learning about databases,I suggest following a SQL tutorial first,before diving into any specifics

Comment: @Phobia: C# works _the same_ with MySQL. The MySQL Connector is basically System.Data for MySQL.

Comment: but you can't connect MySQL to VS.NET through the GUI,you have to write code to make it work

Comment: @Phobia: For newbies, that's what I'd recommend (writing code). That way when the GUI fails (and it will fail one day) they'll understand the magic that makes it work, and how it can be fixed.

Comment: Yes,writing code is indeed better for a beginner,but sometimes you need quick access to data,so you could see the databases and their contents before making requests against tables inside a database,it also helps you figure out which data is coming out from a certain table

Comment: @Phobia: +1, you make a good point but I'd probably advocate using a tool outside of VS (MS SSMSE) for playing with the data and as for quick access: it makes sense for you and I (sometimes), but in the beginning, rushing or glossing over the basics can cause confusion down the line.

Comment: yeah,you can probably use MySQL's CLI or workbench instead,using the CLI is also good for learning some SQL in the process

Comment: The whole ORM or not discussion in this thread is caused by the fact that there's actually two questions being asked: one on learning about data driven applications in c# and one on the business setup you would typically find. The latter will almost always include an ORM tool I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm.... a lot of people have jumped straight from databases to ORM tools.

First choose the tech.... in a Microsoft stack that may mean Sql Server as people have suggested, so download Sql Server Express, a lightweight version of the full thing.

If you have never worked with databases before, I would suggest learning the underlying concepts first eg. tables, joins, indexes etc.

Once you have figured those out and written some queries against a test database, then consider ORM technologies.

Comment: Someone who is not well familiar with databases and database programming should never consider using an ORM, in my opinion. These are tools for people who know what they are doing, not amateurs.

Comment: +1 I fully agree! ORM shouldn't come until basic SQL is well understood.

Answer (score 4):

A business setup (on a microsoft stack) will likely be SQL Server and an ORM tool. From a learning experience, you can just use SQL Express.

I would create a database using the Database Management tool to get to know the DBMS itself.

The .Net framework comes with a query language called, LINQ. This is good to learn. You can use Entity framework to create a model from the database you created (Visual studio will make it easy for you). As the name says, EF creates entities from you database model and you can use LINQ to perform queries on your entities, which the framework will translate to sql.

You are using an abstraction layer in this way, but it's just the way applications are build, so I see no harm in that

Comment: I would seriously *not* recommend using LINQ until the OP understands enough SQL to manage fine without it.

Comment: A valid point. However, he's getting started with c# and databases, not just databases. c# + databases = LINQ. That's why I mentioned it. But ofcourse it's very important to understand what's actually going on at the DB level.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, everyone is suggesting an ORM, but there's a *lot* of value in knowing how to call to the DB directly using SQLConnection/SQLCommand first. Before going straight to an abstraction, figure out what's being abstracted.

Shouldn't take too long as it's fairly straight forward, then you can move on to ORMs etc.

Just my $0.02

Answer (score 1):

You can use any database with C# that you can find an ODBC or OLEDB connector for (so basically everything).  I would recommend that you look at [sqlexpress](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) and use either [linq 2 sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) or entity framework.  ([Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) has much better support while is much more complex.)

Comment: Linq2Sql will only work with SQL Server. And Entity Framework is still "work in progress".

Comment: Yet if you are just learning or on a windows stack then none of that matters.  (And both are much easier to learn that the other monsters from the open source world.)

Comment: Microsoft is investing way more time in Entity framework. @Develop Art: I think Linq to SQL will die a slow death eventually (it's two frameworks solving the same problem). In what way is Entity framework 'work in progress'? Works fine!

Comment: EF is not really "work in progress" anymore, just version 4 is new, and linq2sql has been "discontinued", replaced by EF, so I wouldn't use that.  If you're wanting MS product, EF is the way to go, otherwise pick one of the ORMs out there and go with it.

Comment: Linq2SQL is dead! So if you are going to do a solid application you may consider it.

Comment: EF4 still hasn't its "code-first" part completed. For now you can only use it with the GUI designer which targets it at children.

Comment: @Amir: Doesn't it trouble you that this very site operates on a "dead" technology?

Comment: @Developer It’s a cost/maintenance question.

Answer (score 1):

[Code-First Development with Entity Framework 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx).

Take a look at this. It is a bolt on for C# which allows you to build your objects in code ("Models"), auto create the tables in a real SQL database, and handle your connections.

It isn't *easy* to just pick up and play but, if you get your head around the initial set up using a bit of google and links from the blog above, it can allow you to get up and running with data driven apps without a lot of the donkey work.

Comment: Mmm, this is still CTP and has a number of things that just don't work right yet? So not a good plan to get started I would say. Database first Entity model would a better plan. If you want to learn, you have to know what's going on the in the backend anyways

Comment: I don't recommend EF if performance is considered.

Comment: @Amir: As he is starting I doubt this is the case and I would be surprised if he could write more optimized SQL than is being generated by the framework

Comment: @Syg I agree! But I know too many small hacks becoming large application in companies.

Comment: @Amir This is just a prototype people! .. one year later... Why the hell is this now production code?

Comment: @Syg  May be because the client don't know better.

Comment: I would not recommend anything like this for someone who is just starting to learn SQL/relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how **big your application is and what architecture is used**.
ORM may be considered for larger application.

**EDIT:**

- **Which is the 'best' way from a learning perspective? (IE: What is likely to be used in a business setup)?**

In business sense many companies use ORM. So get familiar with concept why it is there and what problem it solves.

- **If I want to download mySQL/Postgres and connect to that from C#, is that ok?**

You can simply use [ADO.NET](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/csharp/ado-net-odbc.html). However in business case companies use proper architecture to **connect** to databases. So learn the concept of [layered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

Check out this link for [ORM](http://ormeter.net/) compare.

[image]

**LINQ Implementation Scorecard**
[image]

Comment: Nice chart! However, from a 'Business setup' perspective you have to take the Clients whishes into account as well. They might not want U to use anything other then microsoft supported software.

Comment: Agreed. But here you have a document that you can show if you don’t agree with your client decision.

Comment: I really don't think this applies. OP wants to get started learning SQL. They haven't mentioned that they have any specific business need, so this is probably major overkill for someone who's just getting started.

Comment: The question was about learning databases, ORM is a layer on top of a database.

Comment: @james and I typed "ORM may be considered for larger application."

Comment: @Amir Rezaei: Someone who is just starting to learn SQL/RDBMS will have no idea what ORM is, and no idea what either of these graphics represent.

Comment: @Amir - nothing wrong with ORM in it's place but this is a beginner asking how to learn about databases. ORM tech is really irrelevant to what this person is asking about.

Comment: @james He asked "What is likely to be used in a business setup?" and "If I want to download mySQL/Postgres and connect to that from C#, is that ok?" in **business sense** it's not ok to just connect. Add to that he must also consider proper architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned EF, there are a number of other ORM frameworks, here are some of the big ones:

- [N-ORCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/n-orca/)
- [Persist.NET](http://persistdotnet.sourceforge.net/)
- [NPersist](http://npersist.com/home/Default.aspx)
- [Castle ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/)
- [NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET)
- [OR.Net](http://www.ornetmapper.com/)
- [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/)
- [Habanero](http://www.chillisoft.co.za/Habanero.aspx)